# Group by и агрегатная функция с условием

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select, group-by

Предпложим Имеется таблица `test`

```
            ID  |   createdDate |   productId   |   customerId  |
            1   |'2020-01-01'   |       1       |       1       |
            1   |'2020-01-01'   |       2       |       2       |
            1   |'2020-01-01'   |       3       |       1       |
            1   |'2020-01-01'   |       4       |       3       |
            1   |'2020-01-01'   |       5       |       2       |
            1   |'2020-01-01'   |       4       |       3       |
            1   |'2020-08-01'   |       3       |       1       |
            1   |'2020-08-02'   |       6       |       1       |
            1   |'2020-05-01'   |       3       |       1       |
```

для этой таблиц написал следующий запрос:

```
select sum(if(newer=1,1,0)) newerCount, sum(if(newer=0 and older>0,1,0)) olderCount
from (
select
    sum(if(t.createdDate> TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -20, NOW()),1,0)) newer,
    sum(if(t.createdDate< TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -20, NOW()),1,0)) older
from test t where customerId=1 group by productId) result
```

Хочу понять, как работает в этом случае group by.

Вопрос возник, когда при включенном `mysql=only_full_group_by`, я начал получать следующую ошибку `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. Вроде бы при отключенном `only_full_group_by` получаю ожидаемый результат.

Правильно ли я понимаю что этот запрос будет работать следующим образом:

1. создаст группу продуктов (productId). Тогда `в группе productId=3 будут три записи`
2. поочередно выберет createDate из этих записей и вставит в агрегатные функции `sum(if(t.createDate> TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -20, NOW()),1,0))` и  `sum(if(t.createdDate< TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -20, NOW()),1,0))` ? Или возмет первую попавшую createdDate?

Если `createDate`  выбирает поочередно, тогда почему при включеном `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` получаю ошибку?

Comment: *Вопрос возник, когда при включенном mysql=only_full_group_by, я начал получать следующую ошибку this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.* Этого быть не должно - в запросе нет ничего, что приводило бы к этой проблеме. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=273256abf098ee14356cee8800a5174d)

Answer (score 1):

Запрос рабочий, посмотрите [по ссылке](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=273256abf098ee14356cee8800a5174d) из [комментария Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164972/group-by-%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc/1179332#comment2022021_1164972) и вставте там запрос, который не работает.

```
select sum(if(newer=1,1,0)) newerCount, sum(if(newer=0 and older>0,1,0)) olderCount
from (
select
    sum(if(t.createdDate> TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -20, NOW()),1,0)) newer,
    sum(if(t.createdDate< TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -20, NOW()),1,0)) older
from test t where customerId=1 group by productId) result
```